# Installing markdown extension oembed in Google App Engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, markdown, oembed

I managed to install [Python OEmbed](https://github.com/abarmat/python-oembed), an extension to markdown in my system.

When I use it on my system everything works fine,

```
import markdown
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['oembed'])
md.convert('![video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqnh_YJBvOI)')
```

And I get the following answer:

```
u'<iframe width="459" height="344" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zqnh_YJBvOI?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

Then I tryed to just import the library, copying the folder from

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

To my application folder.

Markdown works fine, but if I tryed to load the extension:

```
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['oembed'])
html = md.convert(body)
```

I receive the following error.

```
ImportError: Failed loading extension 'oembed' from 'markdown.extensions.oembed' or 'mdx_oembed'
```

It seems that the extension in intalled somewhere else, but I don't know where.

I've been going in circles for hours, without understanding how to properly use this extension in my app.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking on a different problem for some time, I realized that I had to copy both the folders

```
mdx-oembed
oembed
```

to the main folder of my app

That solved my problems